# string references handling in cpp

Tags: c++, reference

Came across a scenario where I couldn't get a clear picture that what actually happening here.

//This is CPP Program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string nums ( "1234567890" ); //What happens with this memory??
    std::string alpha ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

    std::string &charStr = nums;
    charStr = alpha;

    cout <<"nums : " << nums <<endl;
    cout <<"alpha :" << alpha <<endl;
    cout <<"charStr :" << charStr <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

> nums : abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
>
> alpha :abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
>
> charStr :abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

What happens with memory allocated to nums at the time of initialization?

Comment: It is allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

A reference is an alias. After this line:

```
std::string &charStr = nums;
```

there is one variable which has two names: `nums` and `charStr`. Those two names are equivalent from hereon in; we can't say that the "real" name is one and the "reference" is the other.

The line:

```
charStr = alpha;
```

is an assignment. (The `=` sign has a different meaning in declarations than it does in non-declaration statements; so don't try to draw mental parallels between this line and the declaration of `charStr` earlier).

The effect of assignment on `std::string` is that the left-hand-side copies the characters from the right-hand-side (allocating more storage if necessary); so the string which has names `nums` and `charStr` gets the characters copied from `alpha`.

This is nothing to do with references, it is the same as if you'd written `nums = alpha;` .

Comment: So you means there won't be any memory corruption when nums (lenght is 10) copied with string alpha (length is 26)? at this instance nums will be provided with more storage?

Answer (score 1):

```
 std::string &charStr = nums;
```

Here `charStr` becomes a reference to `nums`. So if you change the value of `charStr` it changes the value of `nums` because both `nums` and `charStr` refer to the same memory location.

```
charStr=alpha;
```

Changing the value of `charStr` changes the value of `nums`.

After this all `nums`,`alpha`,`charStr` have the same value(`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`)

Comment: So I will loose the reference to the string "1234567890"??

Comment: @surender8388 those characters get overwritten, in the same way as if you went `string s; s = "abc";  s = "def";`  - the former contents `"abc"` are now gone

Comment: But nums have length of 10 whereas alpha has a length of 26? is it will update the memory for nums or corruption will happen?

Comment: @surender8388 It will use a new location if new string is longer and free the old memory space